# Prediction based on more dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to predict a score that user gives to a restaurant.

The [data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Restaurant+%26+consumer+data) I have can be grouped into two dataframes

- data about user (taste, personal traits, family, ...)
- data about restaurant(open hours, location, cuisine, ...).

First major question is: **how do I approach this?**

I've already tried basic prediction with the user dataframe (predict one column with few others using RandomForest) and it was pretty straightforward. These dataframes are logically different and I can't merge them into one.

#### What is the best approach when doing prediction like this?

My second question is **what is the best way to handle categorical data (cuisine f.e.)?**

I know I can create a mapping function and convert each value to index, or I can use Categorical from pandas (and probably few other methods). Is there any prefered way to do this?

Comment: This is not really a `pandas` question but rather a methodological question re: machine learning. I would say that https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com/ are better places to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

1) The second dataset is essentially characteristics of the restaurant which might influence the first dataset. Example-opening timings or location are strong factors that a customer could consider. You can use them, merging them at a restaurant level. It could help you to understand how people treat location, timings as a reflection in their score for the restaurant- note here you could even apply clustering and see different customers have different sensitivities to these variables.

For e.g. for frequent occurring customers(who mostly eats out) may be more mindful of location/ timing etc if its a part of their daily routine.

You should apply modelling techniques and do multiple simulations to get variable importance box plots and see if variables like location/ timings have a high variance in their importance scores when calculated on different subsets of data - it would be indicative of different customer sensitivities.

2) You can look at label enconding or one hot enconding or even use the variable as it is? It will helpful here to explain how many levels are there in the data. You can look at `pd.get_dummies` kind of functions

Hope this helps.